# Are there other equations can be derived from $E = mc^2$?

Tags: special-relativity, mass-energy

Are there other equations can be derived from $E = mc^2$?

If mass and energy is interchangeable, does it mean that any other equation that uses mass can be modified by energy/$c^2$? What other equations can be derived from this simple equation in Physics?

Comment: That $E$ is only the energy at rest.

Comment: If you allow the relativistic factor to be there, i.e. $mc^2\rightarrow \gamma mc^2$ you can certainly derive $E^2=m^2c^4+p^2c^2$ from it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes! Certainly in any equation you can think of in physics, the mass of an object can be equivalently replaced by its rest energy. Note the phrase "rest energy", since particles at motion have energies that change with their observed velocity, and also of course there are other forms of energy such as radiation and vibrational energy.

This is one way to see that gravitation must be a function not of mass but of energy. Since all mass is energy but not all energy is mass, this extends the scope of gravitation quite a bit. Starting from this assumption we can show that through general relativity, since angular motion carries energy, it too warps spacetime and has gravitational influence, and so does charge.

Hope that helps!